# Sharepoint 2013 - Videos on asset library no sound

Tags: 2013, video

I have an asset library to store videos, but the videos have no sound when are reproduced and the sound button appears with an X and cannot be toggled.
If a download or save the same video in another library it can be reproduced without any problems and sound perfectly. I've updated silverlight but didn't worked.

Is there a fix for this?

Edit: If I save it on another document library when it opens use quicktime. And the video is MP4.

David

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue in my last project. Sometimes the videos aren't proper which caused them to play no sound. They worked when I used mp4 video from a proper source. I suggest you do the same and verify